# Request mixed with JSON strings and array fields, Losing data in custom function for reduction

Tags: php, arrays, json, performance, reduce

From `POST` Request i am getting and Mixing structure of `JSON` and Fields `Array`; to handle multiple type of elements; i have performing and var_dump to get the passes `$_POST` and get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["json_data"]=>
  string(677) "[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]",
  ["other_data"]=>
  string(11) "Other_Data"
}
```

In PHP server side i am executing a Function that reduce this `$_POST` to this array:

```
array(10) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["countryCode"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["phone"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signup_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signup_password_rep"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signin_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["form"]=>
  string(11) "d-sys-login"
  ["process"]=>
  string(8) "e-signin"
}
```

The script used to meet this output is this:

```
<?php
function buildVirtualData($data)
{
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $val) {
            $chk = buildVirtualData($val);
            if ($chk) {
                $json_obj = json_decode($val, true);
                foreach ($json_obj as $key1 => $json_sub_obj) {
                    foreach ($json_sub_obj as $key2 => $value2) {
                        if ('true' === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = true;
                        } elseif ('false' === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = false;
                        } elseif (is_array($value2)) {
                            $temp = [];
                            foreach ($value2 as $keyof => $valueof) {
                                $temp[$keyof] = buildVirtualData($valueof);
                            }
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = $temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $json_obj;
            } elseif (false == $chk && is_array($val)) {
                $temp = [];
                foreach ($val as $key => $value) {
                    $temp[$key] = buildVirtualData($value);
                }
                $val = $temp;
                return $val;
            } else {
                if ('true' === $val) {
                    $val = true;
                } elseif ('false' === $val) {
                    $val = false;
                }
                return $val;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $chk = valJson($data);
    }
}

function valJson($var)
{
    if (!is_array($var)) {
        return ((json_decode($var) != null) &&
            (is_object(json_decode($var)) || is_array(json_decode($var)))) ? true : false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function reduArray($array)
{
    $result = $array;
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $check = true;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($check) {
            $result = array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$_POST=[];
$_POST['JsonData']='[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]';
$_POST['otherdata']='otherdata';
$_POST=buildVirtualData($_POST);
$_POST=reduArray($_POST);
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

The Main problem is that last member array is missing:

```
  ["other_data"]=>
  string(11) "other_data"
```

1. how can i prevent the lose data?
2. this script can be simpler?

Comment: Maybe you should simplify how you send the parameters in the first place, so you don't need to do this.

Comment: hi @Barmar i can't modify how the part works in javascript that send the data.

Comment: It looks like your code expects all strings in the data to be JSON. I'm having trouble following all the logic, but you need to have it just leave the array element unchanged if `json_decode()` fails, rather than removing it.

Comment: @Barmar As far as I have verified I do not even know where I am removing it element; that's why it's data loss I guess but I can't find that little error in my code; it is assumed that not everything is `JSON`, it is assumed that if it is an `array`, must also go through it until you find the last element that is not an array and use the `key` (textual) and the `value`.

Comment: But when it's not an array, it tries to decode it as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution script but need make it simpler:

```
<?php
    function buildVirtualData($data)
    {
    
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $temp = [];
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $temp[$key] = buildVirtualData($value);
            }
            return reduArray($temp);
        } elseif (valJson($data)) {
            $json_obj = json_decode($data, true);
            foreach ($json_obj as $key1 => $json_sub_obj) {
                foreach ($json_sub_obj as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if (is_array($value2)) {
                        $temp = [];
                        foreach ($value2 as $keyof => $valueof) {
                            $temp[$keyof] = buildVirtualData($valueof);
                        }
                        $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = $temp;
                    } else {
                        if ('true' === $value2 || true === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = true;
                        } elseif ('false' === $value2 || false === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = false;
                        } else {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = $value2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return reduArray($json_obj);
            }
        } else {
            if ('true' === $data || true === $data) {
                $data = true;
            } elseif ('false' === $data || false === $data) {
                $data = false;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
    
    function valJson($var)
    {
        if (!is_array($var)) {
            return ((json_decode($var) != null) &&
                (is_object(json_decode($var)) || is_array(json_decode($var)))) ? true : false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function reduArray($array)
    {
        $result = $array;
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $check = true;
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                    $check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($check) {
                $result = array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    
    $_POST=[];
    $_POST['JsonData']='[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]';
    $_POST['otherdata']='otherdata';
    $_POST=buildVirtualData($_POST);
    $_POST=reduArray($_POST);
    echo var_dump($_POST);
```